# Code to edit a string with either '_' or a character hangs

Tags: python, string

So my piece of code should ideally print out the incomplete word after comparing with a list of characters.

For example, if the word is stackoverflow and the list contains `'s','a','k', 'o', 'r','l'` the output should be

```
s _ a _ k o _ _ r _ l o _
```

my code is

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
'''
secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
returns: string, comprised of letters and underscores that represents
  what letters in secretWord have been guessed so far.
'''
i=0
gameWord=''
while i in range(len(secretWord)):
    if(i%2!=0):
        gameWord+=' ' #to print spaces between characters
    else:
        if(secretWord[i] in lettersGuessed):
            gameWord+=secretWord[i]
        else:
            gameWord+='_'

return gameWord
```

but my code just hangs! and i cannot figure out why!

Comment: There is a comment explaining his if statement. Also, although I agree that a for loop is cleaner, it doesn't answer his question as to why his original code does not work. Rewriting his code doesn't benefit him as a programmer at all. PS. What language is this written in?  Edit:comment irrelevant now that previous comment was deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop if neverending loop hence it hangs (because i=0 is always in your range).

Looks like you need sth like this:

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters and underscores that represents
      what letters in secretWord have been guessed so far.
    '''

    gameWord=''
    for c in secretWord:
        if c in lettersGuessed:
            gameWord += c
        else:
            gameWord += '_'

    return gameWord

print(getGuessedWord('stackoverflow', ['s','a','k', 'o', 'r','l']))
```

output:

> s_a_ko__r_lo_

but if you really want it your way:

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters and underscores that represents
      what letters in secretWord have been guessed so far.
    '''

    i=0
    gameWord=''
    while i in range(len(secretWord)):
        gameWord += ' '
        if(secretWord[i] in lettersGuessed):
            gameWord += secretWord[i]
        else:
            gameWord += '_'
        i += 1
    return gameWord
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to increment your variable i. Otherwise, you are infinitely looping through your while loop!

Add i++ at the bottom inside your loop while loop.

This will fix your infinite loop problem, but will not provide you the expected output you are looking for. You need to rework your if/else logic and you've got it.